# Substring containing backslash in C#

Tags: c#, string, visual-studio-2010, substring

Suppose I have a string `string abc = "ROOT\abcd"`. I want to get the substring "abcd".

Using `abc.substring(4)`, I only get "bcd" in return. It seems like the "a" is not recognized since "\a" is a special character in C#. What can I do to get the entire substring of "abcd"?

Comment: `\a` is an escape sequence, there is no `a` in your string

Comment: You're asking the wrong question. The question is "How can I provide the literal `\a` in a string literal?".

Answer (score 7):

If you want your string to contain a backslash you need to either escape it using a backslash or prepend the string with an @-sign:

```
string abc = @"ROOT\abcd";

string abc = "ROOT\\abcd";
```

Edit: If instead you have created a string by using

```
string a = "\a";
```

and then stored it in your database, neither the string nor the database will contain the letter "a" at that location. Instead it will contain a special character that on some terminals create a beep or blink but on most modern system is simply invisible. If that is the case and not what you wanted in your database you need to store the data again in the correct way. I suggest that you print the strings that you expect to contain a backslash and see if they really do. You could also try to `select` the fields that you want to contain a backslash directly from the sql server management studio (assuming you are using sql server) and check if they really do.

Comment: Assuming abc is a string value that can be changed (defined by a database, in fact), how do I add an @ in front of it, or add a backslash in it, so that it will escape the backslash?

Comment: @NicTamHK How did you get the string into the database? Is there a backslash in the string in the database? Or is there a 0x0A character (the bell character)?

Comment: It's a user name string, so everything would be "ROOT\(username)". This string would then be stored to a variable "abc". But I would like to just isolate the "username" part of this string only.

Answer (score 4):

With your example, you *can't*. `\a` is an [escape sequence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h21280bw.aspx) character as bell(alert).

That means, your string *actually* doesn't have any `abcd` string. Your string has `ROOT`, `\a` and `bcd` strings.

If you can change your regular string literal to [verbatim string literal](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090%28v=vs.71%29.aspx), your string *can* have this.

```
string abc = @"ROOT\abcd";
abc.Substring(5) // returns abcd
```

or double your `/` character like;

```
string abc = "ROOT\\abcd";
abc.Substring(5) // returns abcd
```

Comment: Would you happen to know how to double the `\` character? I can't seem to insert that into my string.

Comment: @NicTamHK If your string has _always_ one \ character, you can use `Replace` method as `abc.Replace(@"\", @"\\")`. Now your `ROOT\abcd` will be `ROOT\\abcd`

Answer (score 1):

Please add '@' infront of your string literal. 
also, you need to use Substring(5) to get 'abcd'. 4 gives you with a '\'

Comment: _"Please add '@' infront of your string literal"_ - why?

Comment: @CodeCaster  '@' will make the escape sequence to be ignored while assigning string value to variable.

Comment: I know. It just isn't in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
        string abc = @"ROOT\abcd";
        string s = abc.Substring(5);
```

Edit:
"\a" is an escape sequence. Use "@" before your string to get the verbatim literal value

Comment: Thats why I added the "@". Thanks for the downvote tho

Comment: _"This should work"_ is not an answer. Explain the problem and what your solution does to address that problem.